# Scrapy - passing response

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to get title and phone number of each object on page.

But phone number is presented like - 0527...getphone

getphone:

```
<a id="phone" onclick="jQuery( '#Handy1').load(
'/ajax/detail/displayphonenumber.php?coded=MDE3Mi8gODUwNzQzMg--&amp;adno=170868912&amp;adsource=quoka+online&amp;catid=27_2710&amp;cusno=19128806' )">getphone</a>
```

ONCLICK - makes ajax with individual data (for every object) and download full phone number in the form -

```
<span>0527555777000</span>
```

But the situation is possible when there is no phone number at all. Because of that I do 'try except' for 'onclick' variable.

I am trying to perform ajax and get full phone number and then to pass the page with phone number downloaded into parse_item()

But I have trouble. When I did debugging with pdb I saw that response in parse_item() == http://www.example.com/ajax/detail/displayphonenumber.php, rather than page of object

How should I fix it? Thanks a lot!

P.S. please, do not propose any tools.. only Scrapy solution

```
def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//div/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            request = scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.phone)
            yield request


def phone(self, response):
        try:
            onclick = response.xpath('//a[@id="phone"]/@onclick').extract()[0]
        except:
            onclick = None    
        if onclick:            
            click_split = onclick.split('?')
            params = click_split[1]
            params_split = params.split('&')
            coded = params_split[0].split('=')
            adno = params_split[1].split('=')
            adsource = params_split[2].split('=')
            catid = params_split[3].split('=')
            cusno = params_split[4].split('=')

            return [ FormRequest("http://www.example.com/ajax/detail/displayphonenumber.php",
                                    formdata={'coded': coded[1],
                                              'adno': adno[1],
                                              'adsource': adsource[1],
                                              'catid': catid[1],
                                              'cusno': cusno[1]},
                                    callback=self.parse_item) ]
        else:
            self.parse_item(response)


def parse_item(self, response):
        item = LotItem()

        try:
            item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()[0]
        except:
            item['title'] = 'no title'

        try:
            item['phone_number'] = response.xpath('//ul/li/text()').extract()[0]
        except:
            item['phone_number'] = 'no phone number'

        yield item
```

Comment: The website may have blocked external ips from doing requests directly to the address, does this work if you do it in your browser? Maybe share an example of the `<a>` tag

Comment: I renewed the post and added <a> tag